# How to setup keyboard switching in Tigervnc via Remmina Remote Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xfce, keyboard-layout, vnc

I am running VNC server on a headless Ubuntu box with `tigervncserver`. `~/.vnc/config` is all commented and has the following examples:

```
# securitytypes=vncauth,tlsvnc
# desktop=sandbox
# geometry=2000x1200
# localhost
# alwaysshared
```

`~/.vnx/xstartup` is following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/bash $HOME/.profile
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
tigervncconfig &
startxfce4 &
```

`/etc/X11/` has no `xorg.conf`, `/etc/X11/xkb/` is empty

When I access my desktop with `Grab all keyboard events` set to `ON`, then I can't switch the keyboard layout. I have

[image]

which has no effect regardless of `Use system defaults` settings.

Somehow I was able to turn on national flag in the lower down corner of the screen

[image]

but it also has no effect. Neither it changes on keystroke combination, nor it changes input language if changed explicitly by mouse.

Where to dig?